# Drupal toggle divs in view

Tags: drupal, view, toggle

Currently I am working on huisartsendorpsstraat.zoetermeergezond.nl/care-practicioners to toggle the workers divs.
What I am trying to accomplish is to only show a maximum of 9 workers, after that a button displays with the show more workers text.

Getting the button ain't no problem, just added it in the footer of the view, but to make it toggle the divs it ain't just not working.
I made sure a .js file is being called from the theme.php file of the theme.

I ain't no Drupal expert, so I am sorry if I am asking stupid questions here.
Has anyone found a way to toggle the divs created inside a view?

Layout:

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first"></div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even"></div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd"></div>
<div class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even"></div>
<div class="views-row views-row-5 views-row-odd views-row-last"></div>
```

thanks a bunch

Comment: Add your js code to post please

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using one of these modules:

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_show_more

They both do same thing basicly -> there are some slight differences. Personally i use the first one. It's quick and easy to set up, no additional custom JS needed. Just install, enable, change your views footer to Views Load More and configure. Good luck!